# SMB Links in Thunderbird

Tags: windows, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird for Windows (3.0.11) and I would like to know how I can put SMB ([Server Message Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) links in the body of my email like you can in Outlook?

Comment: What are SMB links?

Comment: Super Mario Bros.?

Comment: I meant a unc path like \\server\\share or \\server\\share\file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find a pretty good answer to this: 
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=908015&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a I have tried it. It is not the best but hey if somone can delelop an add-on to make it easier, that would be great!!!

Happy New Year all!

Danbo